# Grabbing form data from another page and displaying in html format

Tags: php, html

I have a meal type page (breakfast.php) that a user can select a breakfast package. Once the package selection is confirmed I would like to display that selection in the homepage.php. If I use a input = 'text' and grab the form data it works great but for some reason it will not select the content of my h4 element. Is there a way to grab the selection even if there is say 4 or 5 packages?

This is my code:

breakfast.php

```
<form action="homePage.php" method="post">

<div class= "breakfast">




<u><h2>The Share Collection</h2></u>
</br>
<img src= "\images\Breakfast\breakfast1.jpg" class="funky">
</br>
</br>
<dl>
  <dd>Mini jar of housemade granola: vanilla yoghurt, fresh fruit (v) (6)</dd>
  <dd>Goat cheese, cherry tomato &amp; basil, mushroom tart (v) (8)</dd>
  <dd>Mini slider jamon serrano, fig jam, rocket, brie &amp; black pepper (8)</dd>
  <dd>Chef's mini sweet muffin (v) (8)</dd>
  <dd>Bowl of strawberries &amp; grapes (v) (1)</dd>
</dl>

</br>
<input type='button' value='Select This Package' id='button3' onclick="changemyButton()">

<hr>

<section> 
<h1 id="logo">Total Ordered</h1></section>
<hr>
</br>

<h4 id ="selection" name="foodchoice">   </h4>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" id="button4" value="Submit Your Selection" name="submit">

</center>
</form>
```

homepage.php

```
<p> You have selected <?php echo $_POST["foodchoice"];?><br> as your order!
```

I am new to php and would like the best way to perform this. 
Thanks.

Comment: what is displaying in the homePage.php ,any errors ?

Comment: @VishnuRNair nothing just "you have selected" ---- blank ------ "as your order"

Comment: why do you want to use <h4> for that you can use <input> right ?

Comment: you can use jquery if you still want to sent <h4> value

Comment: ok so how would I do that? Could you explain to me? or send a fiddle? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a different html tag rather than a h4 tag. h4 is a header tag it does not send form data unless you use ajax. For what you're doing you could probably use the select and option tags. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you need , you can change the alert() as you needed

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js">        </script>
 <div class= "breakfast">
 <u><h2>The Share Collection</h2></u>
 </br>
 <img src= "\images\Breakfast\breakfast1.jpg" class="funky">
 </br>
 </br>
 <dl>
 <dd>Mini jar of housemade granola: vanilla yoghurt, fresh fruit (v) (6)</dd>
 <dd>Goat cheese, cherry tomato &amp; basil, mushroom tart (v) (8)</dd>
 <dd>Mini slider jamon serrano, fig jam, rocket, brie &amp; black pepper (8) </dd>
 <dd>Chef's mini sweet muffin (v) (8)</dd>
 <dd>Bowl of strawberries &amp; grapes (v) (1)</dd>
 </dl>
 </br>
 <input type='button' value='Select This Package' id='button3' onclick="changemyButton()">
<hr>
   <section> 
    <h1 id="logo">Total Ordered</h1></section>
<hr>
</br>
<h4 id ="foodchoice" name="foodchoice">  ABCD  </h4>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit Your Selection" name="submit">
</div>
<div id="myRes">DIV TO DISPLAY RESULT</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#submit").click(function() {
    var var1    = $("#foodchoice").html();
    $.ajax({
        url     : 'homePage.php',
        type    : 'post',
        data    : {foodchoice : var1},
        success : function(data) {
            $("#myRes").html(data); 
        },
        error   : function(data) {
            alert("Some thing went wrong"); 
        }
    });
  });

});
</script>
```

Here you can see the breakfast.php is senting the `html` value to the homePage.php

> EDIT :  This is another method you can use it instead of Ajax

```
 <form action="homePage.php" method="post"> 
 <h4 id="meals"  name="meals" > Pizza</h4>
 <input type="hidden" id="hiddeninput" name="hiddeninput"></textarea>
 <input type="submit" id="subs" name="subs" value="Submit"/>
 </form>
 <script>
  $(function(){
    $('#subs').click(function () {
     var mysave = $('#meals').html();
     $('#hiddeninput').val(mysave);
    });
  });
 </script>
```

homePage.php

```
echo $_POST['hiddeninput'];
```

Comment: Unfortunately this code doesn't do anything... Is there a reason why? @Vishnu R Nair

Comment: have you pasted everything ?

Comment: all it does is bring up an alert with heaps of code in it!

Comment: you can change the alert instead of what you need sorry for my english

Comment: great so how do I display my selection, with html and jquery I am not too familiar with jquery...

Comment: If you want to display in current page ie, breakfast.php use  <div> or any kind of tag in the success()

Comment: it will display as like you coded in the homePage.php

Comment: Could you give me an example? Please

Comment: I will send a fiddle

Comment: I don't think I can use PHP in jsfiddle I will update you if you tell me the exact output you require

Comment: I require it to make a div that displays the result that I can post anywhere on my page.

Comment: Sorry but I need to push the data to another page not to the same page, and that just add my old page to the new one

Comment: See my Edits it does exactly what you ask me

Comment: No it doesn't I want the package only to be shown not the whole page. So if the user selects the package "breakfast type 1" then I want a heading in my home page saying "Package Selected" and then the result (Breakfast type 1) to be just whatever has been selected not the whole page!

Answer (score 0):

You should actually loop trough your selected items example:
`if(!empty($_POST['foodchoice'])) {
    foreach($_POST['foodchoice'] as $foodchoise) { //your code })`.

ive created a simple example of your example taken only one checkbox in consider instead of button.

```
<form action="homepage.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="foodchoice[]" value="Fresh Fruit">
<input type="submit" value="Submit!">
```

then the php code:
`You have selected <?php if(!empty($_POST['foodchoice'])) {
    foreach($_POST['foodchoice'] as $foodchoise) {
        ?><br><?php
            echo $foodchoise;}
}?> <br>as your order!`